# @beforeClass annotation on Laravel testcase method ignored

Tags: laravel, annotations, phpunit

In my Laravel 5.1 app's base TestCase which extends `Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase` I have this method:

```
/**
 * @beforeClass
 */
public function resetDatabase()
{
    echo "I never see this message\n";
    $this->artisan("migrate:refresh");
}
```

Other @before and @after annotations in that class is honoured as advertised. Why is this method not called in my unit tests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out that all annotations are not equal!

Inspecting `vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Util/Test.php` shows:

```
private static function isBeforeClassMethod(ReflectionMethod $method)
{
    return $method->isStatic() && strpos($method->getDocComment(), '@beforeClass') !== false;
}


private static function isBeforeMethod(ReflectionMethod $method)
{
    return preg_match('/@before\b/', $method->getDocComment());
}
```

So, if I **make the function static** it is recognised and runs before the class tests. The @before annotation examples that are around were all instance methods, so this lead to the confusion.

Comment: Seeing as you've gotten it working, I have a followup question. How did you get the Artisan command called from within the static method? Obviously `$this` would not work, and me trying to use *any* facade in static methods has resulted in error messages like `Class 'Artisan' not found in /path-to-app/tests/support/DatabaseMigrations.php on line 17`.

Comment: check my answer, I also had the problem that Artisan was not callable from a static method.